# Why does reduceRight return NaN in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, functional-programming, reduce

I'm using Firefox 3.5.7 and within Firebug I'm trying to test the array.reduceRight function, it works for **simple arrays** but when I try something like that I get a **NaN**. Why?

```
>>> var details = [{score : 1}, {score: 2}, {score: 3}];
>>> details
[Object score=1, Object score=2, Object score=3]
>>> details.reduceRight(function(x, y) {return x.score + y.score;}, 0)
NaN
```

I also tried map and at least I can see the .score component of each element:

```
>>> details.map(function(x) {console.log (x.score);})
1
2
3
[undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

I read the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/reduceRight but apparently I can't get it work to sum up all the **score** values in my **details** array. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first argument given to the function is the accumulated value. So the first call to the function will look like `f(0, {score: 1})`. So when doing x.score, you're actually doing 0.score which doesn't work of course. In other words you want `x + y.score`.

Comment: So basically when you pass the initial value to reduceRight, it behaves as a fold.  I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 4):

try this (will convert to numbers as side effect)

```
details.reduceRight(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
  return previousValue + currentValue.score;
}, 0)
```

or this

```
details.reduceRight(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
  var ret = { 'score' : previousValue.score + currentValue.score} ;
  return ret;
}, { 'score' : 0 })
```

Thanks to @sepp2k for pointing out how `{ 'score' : 0 }` was needed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The reduce function should combine two objects with a property "score" into a new object with a property "score."  You're combining them into a number.

Comment: The function should combine an object of type a and an object of type b (where a is the type of the initial value and b is the element type of the array) into an object of type a. a and b don't have to be the same type.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that.  I mostly use Scala, in which the reduce operation always produces a value with the same type as the input list.  In Scala the operation that accumulates the values from a list into a value of another type is called fold.