# JavaScript Reduce Array of objects to object dictionary

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732043/javascript-reduce-on-array-of-objects) on SO to try and understand where I'm going wrong, but not quite getting there.

I have this function :

```
get() {
    var result = {};

    this.filters.forEach(filter => result[filter.name] = filter.value);

    return result;
}
```

It turns this :

```
[
    { name: "Some", value: "20160608" }
]
```

To this :

```
{ Some: "20160608" }
```

And I thought, that is exactly what `reduce` is for, I have an array, and I want one single value at the end of it.

So I thought this :

```
this.filters.reduce((result, filter) => {
    result[filter.name] = filter.value;
    return result;
});
```

But that doesn't produce the correct result.

> 1) Can I use Reduce here?
>
> 2) Why does it not produce the correct result.

From my understanding, the first iteration the result would be an empty object of some description, but it is the array itself.

So how would you go about redefining that on the first iteration - these thoughts provoke the feeling that it isn't right in this situation!

Comment: This is not a filter job. If you want to receive a dictionary object it must be done by reduce. Try @Pranav C Balan's answer.

Comment: I'm not using a filter, or stated filter at all....

Comment: @Redu They aren't using filter. They have an array named `filters` but they're performing a `reduce` on that array.

Comment: @Mike C i meant the first snippet in the question.

Comment: @Redu I know. Read the code. They aren't using `filter`. It's a `forEach` which is being used like `reduce`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Set initial value as object

```
this.filters = this.filters.reduce((result, filter) => {
    result[filter.name] = filter.value;
    return result;
},{});
//-^----------- here
```

```js
var filters = [{
  name: "Some",
  value: "20160608"
}];

filters = filters.reduce((result, filter) => {
  result[filter.name] = filter.value;
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(filters);
```

```js
var filters = [{
  name: "Some",
  value: "20160608"
}];

filters = filters.reduce((result, {name, value}= filter) => (result[name] = value, result), {});

console.log(filters);
```

Comment: You could also use parameter destructuring to shorten this a bit: `(result, {name, value} = filter) => (result[name] = value, result)`

Comment: That doesn't give me the output I'm expecting... could you do it in plnkr or something?

Comment: @CallumLinington : check the snippets added

Comment: Wait one minute, I didn't see that last parameter you supplied to the reduce function.. And I completely missed that when reading the MDN docs. I might as well, delete the question ....

Answer (score 2):

Since 2019 (ES2019) you can go with `Object.fromEntries()` but you need to map to array first.

```
const filtersObject = Object.fromEntries(filters.map(({ name, value }) => [name, value])
```