# Calling reduce to sum array of objects returns NaN

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have code similar to this:

```js
var temp = [ { "y": 32 }, { "y": 60 }, { "y": 60 } ];
var reduced = temp.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.y + b.y;
});

console.log(reduced); // Prints NaN
```

Why does it print `NaN` instead of `152`?

Comment: to explain the issue - once you return the first sum, the typeof `a` will be a Number - which has no `y` property

Comment: check reduce function's callback parameters , what are they ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript reduce on array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732043/javascript-reduce-on-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could use a start value and the add only one value from the array.

```js
var temp=[{"name":"Agency","y":32,"drilldown":{"name":"Agency","categories":["APPS & SI","ERS"],"data":[24,8]}},{"name":"ER","y":60,"drilldown":{"name":"ER","categories":["APPS & SI","ERS"],"data":[7,53]}},{"name":"Direct","y":60,"drilldown":{"name":"Direct","categories":["APPS & SI","ERS"],"data":[31,29]}}];

var reduced = temp.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + a.y;
        //    ^^^ use the last result without property
    }, 0);
//   ^^^ add a start value
console.log(reduced) // r
```

Comment: one liner const reduced = temp.length ? temp.reduce((r, a)  => { return r + a.y; }, 0) : 0;

Comment: @webmaster, even shorter, it takes the start value of reduce for empty arrays: `const reduced = temp.reduce((r, { a }) => r + a, 0);`

Answer (score 10):

short solution: map the collection to integers collection, and reduce it

```
var temp=[{"name":"Agency","y":32,"drilldown":{"name":"Agency","categories":["APPS & SI","ERS"],"data":[24,8]}},{"name":"ER","y":60,"drilldown":{"name":"ER","categories":["APPS & SI","ERS"],"data":[7,53]}},{"name":"Direct","y":60,"drilldown":{"name":"Direct","categories":["APPS & SI","ERS"],"data":[31,29]}}];

var reduced = temp
                .map(function(obj) { return obj.y; })
                .reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });

console.log(reduced);
```