# js - array .reduce returns NaN instead of calculated value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am writing a simple reduce function:

```
var tiles = [
  {
    "date": "2017-11-26",
    "cloudCoverage": 92.2,
    "area": 12055600804
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-11-26",
    "cloudCoverage": 92.78,
    "area": 12055600804
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-11-26",
    "cloudCoverage": 97.29,
    "area": 11609327018
  }
]

function selectDateTile(tiles) {
  return tiles.reduce((tile, currentPick) => {
    console.log('tileArea: ', tile.area, 'currentPick area: ', currentPick.area)
    return tile.area + currentPick.area
  });
}

console.log(selectDateTile(tiles))
```

I would expect it to log the actual values of the objects, and the sum of all the areas:

> "tileArea: " 12055600804 "currentPick area: " 12055600804 "tileArea: "
>   12055600804 "currentPick area: " 24111201608 ...

But the console output I am getting in jsbin is:

> "tileArea: " 12055600804 "currentPick area: " 12055600804 "tileArea: "
>   undefined "currentPick area: " 11609327018 NaN

What am I doing wrong?

[jsbin reference](https://jsbin.com/javivirijo/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array reduce function is returning NAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698450/array-reduce-function-is-returning-nan)

Comment: Or better: [How to call reduce on an array of objects to sum their properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5732043/4642212).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that the first argument passed to your callback is the accumulator, and your callback is supposed to return updated version of that accumulator, which is then used on the next call. So `tile` will only be an entry from the array on the *first* call; after that, it will be whatever your callback returns.

If you're looking to sum up the `area` properties, you want to supply an initial value for the accumulator (the second argument to `reduce`) and then use it as a value, not an object:

```
function selectDateTile(tiles) {
  return tiles.reduce((sum, currentPick) => { // <== Note `sum` parameter
    return sum + currentPick.area;            // <== Using `sum`
  }, 0);                                      // <== 0 as initial value
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var tiles = [
  {
    "date": "2017-11-26",
    "cloudCoverage": 92.2,
    "area": 12055600804
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-11-26",
    "cloudCoverage": 92.78,
    "area": 12055600804
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-11-26",
    "cloudCoverage": 97.29,
    "area": 11609327018
  }
];

function selectDateTile(tiles) {
  return tiles.reduce((sum, currentPick) => { // <== Note `sum` parameter
    return sum + currentPick.area;            // <== Using `sum`
  }, 0);                                      // <== 0 as initial value
}

console.log(selectDateTile(tiles));
```

You **could** write your callback so that it detected whether it was passed an entry as the first parameter or the accumulator, but it unnecessarily complicates the code.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are not checking if the `tile` has `area` property or not since it is an *accumulator* and after first iteration it will be just a *number*

```
function selectDateTile(tiles) {
  return tiles.reduce((tile, currentPick) => {
    console.log('tileArea: ', tile.area, 'currentPick area: ', currentPick.area)
    return tile.area ? tile.area + currentPick.area : tile + currentPick.area;
  });
}
```