# Sum of fields in an array of objects with reduce returns NaN

Tags: javascript, reduce

I am seeing a strange behaviour with the `reduce` function in javascript.

I have an array of objects, made like this:

```
[ { a:1 }, {a:2}, ... ]
```

I need the sum of the `a` property inside every object, so I wrote this:

```
const array = [{a:1}, {a:2}];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator.a + currentValue.a;
console.log(array.reduce(reducer));
```

This works as expected.

If I try to run the same code with an array containing a single object, I get that object as the result of the `reduce` call (and this is expected behaviour), so I added a default value to the reduce function call like this:

```
const array = [{a:1}];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator.a + currentValue.a;
console.log(array.reduce(reducer, {a: 0}));
```

And this also works like a charm.

I would expect to be able to run the second version of the reduce call with an array with more than one element, such as:

```
const array = [{a:1}, {a:2}];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator.a + currentValue.a;
console.log(array.reduce(reducer, {a: 0}));
```

But this returns `NaN` and I don't understand why.
Could anyone please explain me?

Comment: Your 1st attempt won't work with `const array = [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}];`. Because after the 1st iteration, accumulator will be a number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array reduce function is returning NAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698450/array-reduce-function-is-returning-nan)

Comment: Or better: [Javascript reduce on array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5732043/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), if you don't state an initial value, the 1st item of the array becomes the initial value. Since you want a number, and not an object as the result, initialize with 0. Since the accumulator is now a number, and not an object, use `accumulator` instead of `accumulator.a` in the function's body:

```js
const array = [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.a;
console.log(array.reduce(reducer, 0));
```

You can also check if the accumulator is an object, and then try to access it's property, but I find it more confusing than simply stating an initial value:

```js
const array = [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => (typeof accumulator === 'object' ? accumulator.a : accumulator) + currentValue.a;
console.log(array.reduce(reducer));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `reducer` returns a *number value* (sum of `accumulator.a + currentValue.a`) while your `accumulator` is an object.

Either initialize `accumulator` to `0` or return the `accumulator` itself, make it

```
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => (accumulator.a += currentValue.a, accumulator);
```

**Demo**

```js
const array = [{
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 2
}];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => (accumulator.a += currentValue.a, accumulator);
console.log(array.reduce(reducer, {
  a: 0
}));
```

**Note**

- This reducer will return `{"a":3}`, but if you only want the *sum* value, print its property `a`

i.e.

```
console.log(array.reduce(reducer, {
  a: 0
}).a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your reducer function as

```
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => ({ a: accumulator.a + currentValue.a });
```

your orignal code doesn't work as you return a `Number` instead of an object whose property you were accessing.