# reduce() method is returning NaN from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce

I want to obtain the sum of total of votes using `reduce()`, but I am always receiving `NaN` as a result, instead of 20.

I have the following js code:

```js
 const choiseArray=[
    {choice: "Shooter",url:"/questions/10/choices/01",votes:3},
    {choice: "Shooter2",url:"/questions/10/choices/02",votes:2},
    {choice: "Shooter3",url:"/questions/10/choices/03",votes:4},
    {choice: "Shooter3",url:"/questions/10/choices/03",votes:11},
];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => parseInt(accumulator.votes) + parseInt(currentValue.votes);

const totalVotes= choiseArray.reduce(reducer);

console.info(totalVotes);
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong and why?

Comment: `const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue.votes;` and add a start value: `const totalVotes= choiseArray.reduce(reducer, 0);`

Comment: What's wrong is after first iteration accumulator is a number not object. Add a breakpoint and step through it to see

Comment: Why someone put -1, what is wrong with the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array reduce function is returning NAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698450/array-reduce-function-is-returning-nan)

Comment: Or better: [How to call reduce on an array of objects to sum their properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5732043/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your current problem is**: In the first iteration, you have `accumulator.votes + currentValue.votes`, in the second, `accumulator` is now a number (the result of the calculation), not an `object` anymore, so it doesn't have the property `votes`, that's why you get `NaN`

**Solution**:
Call your function passing `0` as `reduce` second parameter, this will be the accumulator, then in your function just sum values into it, not accessing `accumulator.votes`.

```js
const choiseArray = [{
    choice: "Shooter",
    url: "/questions/10/choices/01",
    votes: 3
  },
  {
    choice: "Shooter2",
    url: "/questions/10/choices/02",
    votes: 2
  },
  {
    choice: "Shooter3",
    url: "/questions/10/choices/03",
    votes: 4
  },
  {
    choice: "Shooter3",
    url: "/questions/10/choices/03",
    votes: 11
  },
];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + parseInt(currentValue.votes);

const totalVotes = choiseArray.reduce(reducer, 0);

console.log("Total Votes: " + totalVotes);
```