# JavaScript `reduce` yielding NaN when trying to sum simple floats

Tags: javascript

`let totalIn = transactions.reduce((a, b) => Number(a.amount) + Number(b.amount));`

What could be reasons that this is yielding NaN? Each object in the `transactions` array has an `amount` property and each `amount` property is holding a string that is convertible to a float.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a example of `transactions`.

Comment: the second argument of reduce is also missing, which is the initial value but in the case of an object You should do it externally

Comment: `let totalIn = transactions.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.amount, 0);` is probably what you want

Comment: The correct code would be `let totalIn = transactions.reduce((total, item) => total += Number(item.amount), 0)`. You are misinterpreting the arguments of the reduce callback function and you did not initialize the accumulator.

Comment: Thanks for all responses. It's fixed now :)

Comment: Duplicate of [Calling reduce to sum array of objects returns NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698450/calling-reduce-to-sum-array-of-objects-returns-nan)

Answer (score 5):

The `.reduce()` method passes the accumulator value as the first parameter. After the first iteration, therefore, `a` will not be one of the values in your array: it will be the numeric sum of two numbers. Therefore it won't have an "amount" property, so `Number(a.amount)` will be `NaN`.

The way I personally would deal with that would be to ensure that every iteration is the same:

```
let totalIn = transactions.reduce((a, b) => a + Number(b.amount), 0);
```

By passing in a second parameter to `.reduce()` to be used as the initial value of the accumulator, every call to the reduce callback will be similar (a number as `a` and one of your array element objects as `b`).