# How to get the sum of stringslength with an array of strings with reduce in js

Tags: javascript, iterator, reduce

as discribed i would love to get the sum of the Strings in the Array with the reduce function.

```
const fruitsb = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'pineapple'];

const sumtwo = fruitsb.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  return accumulator.length + currentValue.length;
});

console.log(sumtwo);
```

So far i tried to get the length of my two parameters but when i console.log it i just get a Nan.

Comment: I downvoted because you would find the problem using your debugger. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698450/calling-reduce-to-sum-array-of-objects-returns-nan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a number, so you do not need to access the `length` property of `accumulator`. Besides that, you'd need to specify an initial value of 0, so JavaScript knows it's a number from the beginning, because by default, it is set to the first value from the array you're trying to reduce (in this case `apple`).

Your fixed code would look like this.

```js
const fruitsb = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'pineapple'];
    
const sumtwo = fruitsb.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
      return accumulator + currentValue.length; // accumulator is already a number, no need to access its length
}, 0); // Initial value of 0
    
console.log(sumtwo);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `join()` array method, then find the length

```js
const fruitsb = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'pineapple'];
const sumtwo = fruitsb.join('');

console.log(sumtwo.length);
```