# How to sum up properties of an array of objects with reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have the following array:

```
var BUILDINGS = [
    { production: {"numberProd": 6}},
    { production: {"numberProd": 11}},
    { production: {"numberProd": 14}},
];
```

I'm trying to use `reduce()` to add up the sum of these productions. I've tried to the following:

```
BUILDINGS.reduce(function(a,b) {return a.production.numberProd + b.production.numberProd});
```

But when I run the code I get the value `NaN`.

I was wondering how to properly set up the `reduce()` statement.
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript reduce on array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732043/javascript-reduce-on-array-of-objects). How to properly set up `reduce` is described in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass initial value of `0` which will be assigned to the first parameter `a` in the initial iteration of `reduce()`.

Try the following:

```js
var BUILDINGS = [
    { production: {"numberProd": 6}},
    { production: {"numberProd": 11}},
    { production: {"numberProd": 14}},
];
var prod = BUILDINGS.reduce(function(a,b) {
  return a + b.production.numberProd;
}, 0);

console.log('Total:', prod);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close:

```
BUILDINGS.reduce(function(a,b) {return a + b.production.numberProd}, 0);
```

---

```
BUILDINGS.reduce((currentValue, nextBuilding) => {
  return currentValue + nextBuilding.production.numberProd
}, 0) // 0 is the first value
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
var BUILDINGS = [
    { production: {"numberProd": 6}},
    { production: {"numberProd": 11}},
    { production: {"numberProd": 14}},
];

console.log(BUILDINGS.reduce((sum, item) => {
  sum += item.production.numberProd;
  return sum;
}, 0));
```

If you don't pass the initial value as `0`, you will get a `NaN` as the result.