# Get multiple sets from JSON for different keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hi I'm stuck with this problem. Hopefully somebody can give me some advice.

I've got a JSON with the last day changes in a application that I work on. I want to get 3 datasets from it. And want to keep de right order in date like the example below:

```
"log": [{
        "objectname": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "type": "CREATE",
        "timenormal": "Sun Feb 09 2020 22:02:26 GMT+0100",
        "closesthours": 22
    }, {
        "objectname": "This is a Dummy",
        "type": "CREATE",
        "timenormal": "Sun Feb 09 2020 23:27:46 GMT+0100",
        "closesthours": 23
    },{
        "objectname": "Deleted test",
        "type": "DELETE",
        "timenormal": "Mon Feb 10 2020 00:30:14 GMT+0100",
        "closesthours": 1
    },{
        "objectname": "Qwerty",
        "type": "CREATE",
        "timenormal": "Mon Feb 10 2020 00:45:04 GMT+0100",
        "closesthours": 1
    },{
        "objectname": "Deleted test",
        "type": "DELETE",
        "timenormal": "Mon Feb 10 2020 04:45:14 GMT+0100",
        "closesthours": 5
    }, {
        "objectname": "Hello World",
        "type": "CREATE",
        "timenormal": "Mon Feb 10 2020 10:51:22 GMT+0100",
        "closesthours": 11
    }, {
        "objectname": "Another one",
        "type": "CREATE",
        "timenormal": "Mon Feb 10 2020 10:41:22 GMT+0100",
        "closesthours": 11
    }, {
        "objectname": "ABC",
        "type": "CREATE",
        "timenormal": "Mon Feb 10 2020 21:16:57 GMT+0100",
        "closesthours": 21
    }, {
        "objectname": "test dummy",
        "type": "DELETE",
        "timenormal": "Mon Feb 10 2020 21:17:00 GMT+0100",
        "closesthours": 21
    }
]
```

I know that following is possible to use map for the 'closesthours':

```
jsondata['log'].map(function(value, index) {return value['closesthours']});
[22, 23, 1, 1, 5, 11, 11, 21, 21]
```

From there on, I'm stuck. The **3 datasets** I want is:

**1.)** A map with the closesthours combined:

```
{"hours":"22,23,1,5,11,21"}
```

**2 & 3)** Then I realy want to get a count for occurences by closesthours in the dataset for the two types (DELETE and CREATE)
For example, I want to get the following back(with the 0 if that type doesn't have te closesthours):

```
{"type":"CREATE","groupcount":"1,1,1,0,2,1"}
{"type":"DELETE","groupcount":"0,0,1,1,0,1"}
```

How can I do this in javascript?

Comment: For getting the map of all closest hours: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865/215552, but you should invest some time in learning the [`reduce` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5732043/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first build one object with unique hours array and every type and then use another loop to fill `groupcount` array for each type using previously created object.

```js
const data = [{"objectname":"Lorem Ipsum","type":"CREATE","timenormal":"Sun Feb 09 2020 22:02:26 GMT+0100","closesthours":22},{"objectname":"This is a Dummy","type":"CREATE","timenormal":"Sun Feb 09 2020 23:27:46 GMT+0100","closesthours":23},{"objectname":"Deleted test","type":"DELETE","timenormal":"Mon Feb 10 2020 00:30:14 GMT+0100","closesthours":1},{"objectname":"Qwerty","type":"CREATE","timenormal":"Mon Feb 10 2020 00:45:04 GMT+0100","closesthours":1},{"objectname":"Deleted test","type":"DELETE","timenormal":"Mon Feb 10 2020 04:45:14 GMT+0100","closesthours":5},{"objectname":"Hello World","type":"CREATE","timenormal":"Mon Feb 10 2020 10:51:22 GMT+0100","closesthours":11},{"objectname":"Another one","type":"CREATE","timenormal":"Mon Feb 10 2020 10:41:22 GMT+0100","closesthours":11},{"objectname":"ABC","type":"CREATE","timenormal":"Mon Feb 10 2020 21:16:57 GMT+0100","closesthours":21},{"objectname":"test dummy","type":"DELETE","timenormal":"Mon Feb 10 2020 21:17:00 GMT+0100","closesthours":21}]

const {hours, types} = data.reduce((r, {type, closesthours}, i) => {
  r.hours = [...new Set([...r.hours, closesthours] || [])]
  r.types[type] = {type, groupcount: []}
  return r;
}, {hours: [], types: {}});

data.forEach(({type, closesthours}) => {
  const index = hours.indexOf(closesthours);
  for(let t in types) {
    if(types[t].groupcount[index] == undefined) {
      types[t].groupcount[index] = 0
    }
    
    if(t == type) {
      types[t].groupcount[index] += 1
    } 
  } 
});

console.log(hours)
console.log(Object.values(types))
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much.This helped me and learned a lot with your snippet. :-)